# Adding a column thats Max value of lookback x row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My Orignal dataframe is like:

```
   Date  Price
0     0    100
1     1     10
2     2     30
3     3     20
4     4     50
```

Price are float.

I need to be able to add a column that's "Max of last x days" including today
 to the orignal dataframe .

The result should be
x=3

```
  Date   Price   Max_3Days
    0      100    N/A
    1      10     N/A
    2      30     100
    3      20     30
    4      50     50
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this was your input,

```
df

   Date  Price
0     0    100
1     1     10
2     2     30
3     3     20
4     4     50
```

You can get this done with a rolling max.

```
df.Price.rolling(3).max()

0      NaN
1      NaN
2    100.0
3     30.0
4     50.0
Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

Or, if you *really* want `N/A` instead of NaNs, thereby destroying performance by mixing strings and objects, chain a `fillna` call after.

```
df.Price.rolling(3).max().fillna('N/A')

0    N/A
1    N/A
2    100
3     30
4     50
Name: Price, dtype: object
```

---

Note! I don't often mention older version APIs, but for `0.17` and below, there's [`pd.rolling_max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.rolling_max.html) -

```
pd.rolling_max(df.Price, window=3)

0      NaN
1      NaN
2    100.0
3     30.0
4     50.0
Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

Deprecated in recent versions, use `pd.Series.Rolling.max` instead.

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thank you very much.